# How to recover an electrum wallet from seed

Tags: electrum, wallet-recovery, seed

A service I used some years ago is shutting down. I withdrew some coin but it went to an old address. I believe it was my old electrum wallet that I only have the seed for. How to recover my bitcoin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First [download Electrum](https://download.electrum.org/), try to get a version closest to the one you were using. Get the portable version because you may need to get a higher version if it doesn't work.

Open the program, File -> new/restore -> enter in your seed when asked.

When it asks for a password, it means a new password to save this wallet with encryption.

Then wait for the syncing to happen.

Comment: When you enter the seed the password is required to encrypt the seed on your disk. The seed itself is the password that unlocks everything - this is why it needs to be encrypted on the disk. The password is not required when recovering from seed you can enter any password you want.

Comment: Maybe that's true in newer versions. You need the original seed and password in the 1.x versions. Please don't overwrite old passwords .-.

Comment: @Eddie that's not true. Also you shouldn't be using 1.x anyway. It is unsafe to use such an old version. Always use the latest version of electrum.

Comment: This was written for people with wallets from 2017, if you have an updated answer just post it!